# Three.js can't load 3D model

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am trying to load a custom 3D model into Three.js but I cant get it to work. I am working from the official site's example to do this, the link to the example is given below.

```
https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas {width: 100%; height: 100%;};
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src = "./scripts/Imported/three.js"></script>
        <script src="./scripts/Digital_Twin.js"></script>
        <script>
            // My Javascript will go here.
            Load_Digital_Twin();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`Digital_Twin.js`:

```
import { GLTFLoader } from "./Imported/GLTFLoader.js";  

/**/
var Load_Part = {};

/**/
Load_Part.Cutter = function () {
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();

    loader.load('../models/CutterHead.glb', function ( gltf ) {

        scene.add( gltf.scene );

    }, undefined, function ( error ) {

        console.error( error );

    } );
};

/**/
function Load_Digital_Twin () {
    Digital_Twin.Load_Part.Cutter();
}
```

The chrome console output is as follows:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at Digital_Twin.js:1:1)
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Load_Digital_Twin is not defined at (index):16:13 (anonymous) @ (index):16

According to the error I should change the type of the script to a 'module', but the example doesn't do it and when I do it I get other complications where my functions can't be called outside of the file itself (For example `Load_Digital_Twin();` in index.html).

Comment: can you try type="module" in Digital_Twin.js import script. like this: 
<script type="module" src="./scripts/Digital_Twin.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks for the support @ahmetkilinc I have tried it but then when I try to call my ```Load_Digital_Twin();``` function it does not recognize it anymore.